# Can I get a list of constructors (like with `Typeable`, `Data`), but based on type inference instead of a run-time representation of my type?

Tags: haskell, types, introspection

I had a hard time putting together the question. Let's try step by step:

I have a Haskell type class (that represents a keyboard layout fyi):

```hs
class Data key => Palantype key where
  
  -- the instance has to provide this mapping
  keyCode :: key -> Char

  -- but the reverse is required, too:
  toKeys :: Char -> [key]
```

I can provide a (not-so-efficient) default implementation for `toKeys` based on `Typeable` and `Data`:

```hs
-- | override for efficiency
toKeys :: key -> Char -> [key]
toKeys k c =
  let t = dataTypeOf k
      ks = fromConstr . indexConstr t <$> [1..(maxConstrIndex t)]
      m = foldl (\m k -> Map.insertWith (++) (keyCode k) [k] m) Map.empty ks
  in  fromMaybe [] $ Map.lookup c m
```

... and the above code works. Nice.

However, there is a problem. The default implementation requires `key` as first argument, the reason being: `Data` requires a run-time representation of the type. This is provided by `DataType`, using `dataTypeOf :: a -> DataType`.

I have to adjust the type signature of `toKeys` and always provide a not-so-meaningful dummy key. I understand that this is how `Data.Data` works. But is there a way to get the same magic based on the type variable `key`?

There is the function `typeRep` in `Data.Typeable` that seems to work that way:

```hs
typeRep :: forall proxy a. Typeable a => proxy a -> TypeRep
```

But all the workings of `Data` (`fromConstr`, `indexConstr`, `maxConstrIndex`) rely on the run-time representation `DataType` (for a reason?).

---

An elegant solution using `Data.Proxied`:

```hs
toKeys :: Char -> [key]
toKeys c =
  let t = dataTypeOfProxied (Proxy :: Proxy key)
      ks = fromConstr . indexConstr t <$> [1..(maxConstrIndex t)]
      m = foldl (\m k -> Map.insertWith (++) (keyCode k) [k] m) Map.empty ks
  in  fromMaybe [] $ Map.lookup c m
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick test in GHCi:

```
> dataTypeOf (undefined :: Int)
DataType {tycon = "Prelude.Int", datarep = IntRep}
```

This reveals that `dataTypeOf` does not really need a runtime value, and the first argument is only used for its type. You can (and should) write something like

```
toKeys :: forall key . Data key => Char -> [key]
toKeys c =
   let t = dataTypeOf (undefined :: key)
   ...
```

In my opinion, this interface is not how it should be today, but we still have it because of historical reasons. When `Data` was designed, I guess, we had no `AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications` so we used "unevaluated" arguments and/or proxies.

If `Data` were designed today, I guess we would have the ambiguous type

```
dataTypeOf :: forall a . Data a => DataType
```

and we would use that as `dataTypeOf @key`.

Comment: I was browsing hackage to figure out the implementation of `dataTypeOf` ... repl ftw

Comment: and I guess `dataTypeOf :: Proxy t -> DataType` would be a bit of a nicer interface

Comment: @ruben.moor We have [that](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/proxied-0.3.1/docs/Data-Proxied.html#v:dataTypeOfProxied), but ambiguous types are even better, IMO.

Comment: One day.. `forall a -> Data a => DataType`